# Discord.py | How do I get a list of all voice-channels in a guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I defined my guild as

```
guild = client.get_guild(319545112629608449)
```

but I don't know how to process any further. I googled for around an hour by now but everything that apparently used to work doesn't work anymore. I am using the latest version of discord.py. Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Guild` has the attribute `voice_channels`, as well as many others like `text_channels` or `channels`

```py
guild = client.get_guild(...)
vc_channels = guild.voice_channels
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.voice_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_channels)